# How to fix error "COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder/public: no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I am trying to build a custom nginx docker image, where I want to overwrite the `default.conf` file at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`. 
Following is the code of Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

But while building the image, I am getting following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/2 : FROM nginx
# Executing 1 build trigger
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder221277665/public: no such file or directory
```

As per the logs, it is failing on the first instruction. And it is pointing to the `public` folder.

Please help me understanding the problem as why it could be pointing to the `public` folder? Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You haven't done a `docker build -t nginx` on this system with some other Dockerfile, have you?  This sounds like an ONBUILD hook but the official nginx image doesn't have one.

Comment: I have nginx images in other projects but with different tags. I haven't created built any image with this tag.

Comment: Nothing stands out from what you've shown, please include the build command you ran.

Comment: To eliminate anything from a bad nginx image, run a `docker pull nginx`.

Comment: @BMitch: I did `docker pull nginx` and built the image again, and it fixed the issue. Thank you. I was struggling with this issue from last 2 days.

Comment: @BMitch If you can please add it as an answer, then I will accept it. It can help someone else like me to reach a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David hinted in the comments, this command looks like it came from an ONBUILD instruction from the base image. Since nginx doesn't ship with that command, this points to another image on the host that was tagged as nginx. Pulling a fresh copy of nginx from upstream can fix that:

```
docker pull nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a .dockerignore file which ignores the public folder?

Comment: No, I don't have .dockerignore file in this project.